# Chart.js margins

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'd like to know how to access the left and right margins of a chart in Chart.js. [image]

[image]

Looking for something like "chart.canvas.marginLeft".

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

With

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

the following will get you your 'margins'

```
alert(chart.scale.xScalePaddingLeft);
alert(chart.scale.xScalePaddingRight);
```